No overload matches this call. Typescript error
[[enter image description enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/oTQcU5oA.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/LRODtLyd.png)
This is the error .
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type '(req: ModifiedRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
Type '(req: ModifiedRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
Property 'user' is missing in type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' but required in type 'ModifiedRequest'.ts(2769)
I am stuck in this error since 3 days and it is giving me depression actually I am new to typescript and working in one of the project and while using middleware this gave me error . Please help me to resolve the error or give some guide how to resolve the error .
I am trying to use that authentication middleware in my route . enter image description here

Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions. Currently this question risks being closed as needing debugging details, as images don't count as [mre]s.
